# Ngrx dispatch add action does not update the view automatically but just after refresh

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

As per title I am migrating an app to ngrx. I have a form and an add button with a table aside that was updated just by recalling the get transactions fromt he backend. I did something similar with ngrx in the addTransaction effect but the view is not updated(only after refresh)
As per title when I use my selector in my component I got undefined value. Here is my reducer

```js
export interface State extends AppState.State {
  transactions: TransactionState
}
export interface TransactionState {
  transactions: Transaction[]
  error: string
}
const initialState: TransactionState = {
  transactions: [],
  error: '',
}

export const transactionReducer = createReducer<TransactionState>(
  initialState,
  on(TransactionActions.loadTransactions, (state, action) => {
    return { ...state, transactions: action.transactions }
  }),
  on(
    TransactionActions.errorItem,
    (state, action): TransactionState => {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.message,
      }
    },
  ),
)
export const selectFeature = (state: State) => state.transactions
export const selectTransactions = createSelector(
  selectFeature,
  (state: TransactionState) => state.transactions,
)
```

Here my actions

```js
export const getTransactions = createAction('[Transaction] get transactions')

export const loadTransactions = createAction(
  '[Transaction] load transactions',
  props<{ transactions: Transaction[] }>(),
)
export const addTransaction = createAction(
  '[Transaction] add transaction',
  props<{ transaction: Transaction }>(),
)
```

And here my effect that make a call to backend service

```js
@Injectable()
export class TransactionEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private transactionService: TransactionService,) {}

  loadTransactions$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getTransactions),
      mergeMap((action) => {
        console.log('inside effect')

        return this.transactionService.getTransactionsByUsername(3).pipe(
          map((data) => {
            console.log('data', data)
            return loadTransactions({ transactions: data })
          }),
          catchError((error) =>
            of({
              type: '[Transaction] error item',
              message: error,
            }),
          ),
        )
      }),
    ),
  )
          
 

  addTransaction$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(addTransaction),
      switchMap((action) => {
        this.transactionService
          .createTransaction(action.transaction)
          .subscribe((res) => {
            this._snackBar.open(res.message, 'Close', {
              duration: 1500,
              panelClass: ['snackbar-success'],
            })
          })
        const transactionsLoaded = this.transactionService.getTransactionsByUsername(
          3,
        )
        return of({
          type: '[Transaction] load transactions',
          transactions: transactionsLoaded,
        })
      }),
      catchError((error) =>
        of({
          type: '[Transaction] error item',
          message: error,
        }),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

When I dispactch the `addTransaction` action in my component the transaction is created successfully but the view is not updated(I tried also to re-respatch the `getTransactions` action) but only after refresh it works.

```js
onSaveTransaction(newTransaction) {
  this.store.dispatch(
    TransactionActions.addTransaction({ transaction: newTransaction }),
  )
```

Could someone explain me what is going on and what  am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Do you use `onPush` change detection strategy?

Comment: no I am using the default one. I tried to change it now in all component but the transactions are get after I start filling the form and after I add a new one still not working.

Comment: In the reducer at `TransactionActions.loadTransactions` the `action.transactions` might have the same reference, as previously. Could you please try `[...action.transactions]` there to make sure, that the reference will be different as previously?

Comment: Ok by doing   on(TransactionActions.loadTransactions, (state, action) => {
    return { ...state, transactions: [...action.transactions] }
  }), the new object is put on the bottom on the list. By default I was calling the service to get it ordered on top is possible to do that? but in the console I am getting TypeError: action.transactions is not iterable
    at transaction.reducer.ts:26 (That is the edited)

Comment: Your `transactionsLoaded` constant is an Observable, not a `Transaction[]` array. You need to change the way you implement the Observables in your `addTransaction$` effect. You should not be subscribing to Observables inside another Observable's pipe.

Comment: @WillAlexander thank you. Do you have other tips on how to proceed?I am quite new to ngrx